# XML file Parsing in text file (CSV) using XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

Trying to Parse below mention XML file into CSV Using XSLT. Expected outcome of below mention XML file in .CSV file using XSL parsing

The Sample XML File is mentioned below

```
<SCHOOLS>
    <SCHOOL_DATA>
        <SCHOOL>
            <SCHOOL_NAME>Convent International</SCHOOL_NAME>
            <SCHOOL_ADDRESS>Near x-Street</SCHOOL_ADDRESS>
        </SCHOOL>
        <STUDENT_DTLS>
            <STUDENT>
                <STUDENT_NAME>Maria</STUDENT_NAME>
                <STUDENT_CLASS>10</STUDENT_CLASS>
            </STUDENT>
            <STUDENT>
                <STUDENT_NAME>John</STUDENT_NAME>
                <STUDENT_CLASS>12</STUDENT_CLASS>
            </STUDENT>
        </STUDENT_DTLS>
        <SCHOOL_AWARDS>
            <AWARDS>
                <AWARD_NAME>A1</AWARD_NAME>
                <AWARD_DATE>D1</AWARD_DATE>
            </AWARDS>
            <AWARDS>
                <AWARD_NAME>A2</AWARD_NAME>
                <AWARD_DATE>D2</AWARD_DATE>
            </AWARDS>
            <AWARDS>
                <AWARD_NAME>A3</AWARD_NAME>
                <AWARD_DATE>D3</AWARD_DATE>
            </AWARDS>
            <AWARDS>
                <AWARD_NAME>A4</AWARD_NAME>
                <AWARD_DATE>D4</AWARD_DATE>
            </AWARDS>
        </SCHOOL_AWARDS>
    </SCHOOL_DATA>
</SCHOOLS>
```

Expected output in .csv using Xsl parsing with above sample data

```
SCHOOL_NAME,SCHOOL_ADDRESS,STUDENT_NAME,STUDENT_CLASS,AWARD_NAME,AWARD_DATE
Convent International,Near x-Street,Maria,10,A1,D1
,,John,12,A2,D2
,,,,A3,D3
,,,,A4,D4
```

[image: Expected Out Put CSV Open in Excel]

Getting Out Put on parsing xml file

```
SCHOOL_NAME,SCHOOL_ADDRESS,STUDENT_NAME,STUDENT_CLASS,AWARD_NAME,AWARD_DATE
Convent International,Near x-Street
,,Maria,10
,,John,12
,,,,A1,D1
,,,,A2,D2
,,,,A3,D3
,,,,A4,D4
```

[image: Getting output CSV Open in Excel]

Xslt File

```
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
SCHOOL_NAME,SCHOOL_ADDRESS,STUDENT_NAME,STUDENT_CLASS,AWARD_NAME,AWARD_DATE
<xsl:for-each select="SCHOOLS/SCHOOL_DATA"> 
<xsl:for-each select="SCHOOL"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(SCHOOL_NAME,',',SCHOOL_ADDRESS,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="STUDENT_DTLS/STUDENT"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('',',','',',',STUDENT_NAME,',',STUDENT_CLASS,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="SCHOOL_AWARDS/AWARDS"> 
    <xsl:value-of 
select="concat('',',','',',','',',','',',',AWARD_NAME,',',AWARD_DATE,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your expected output associates the 1st award with the 1st student, and the 2nd award with the 2nd student. I see no such association in the source XML. Please clarify the logic that needs to be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

If (as it seems) you just want a list of all schools in columns 1 & 2, a list of all students in columns 3 & 4, and a list of all awards in columns 5 & 6, with no connection between the three lists, then try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/SCHOOLS">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>SCHOOL_NAME,SCHOOL_ADDRESS,STUDENT_NAME,STUDENT_CLASS,AWARD_NAME,AWARD_DATE&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- generate rows -->
    <xsl:call-template name="write-rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="schools" select="SCHOOL_DATA/SCHOOL"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="students" select="SCHOOL_DATA/STUDENT_DTLS/STUDENT"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="awards" select="SCHOOL_DATA/SCHOOL_AWARDS/AWARDS"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="write-rows">
    <xsl:param name="schools"/>
    <xsl:param name="students"/>
    <xsl:param name="awards"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <!-- SCHOOL -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$schools[$i]/SCHOOL_NAME"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
    <xsl:value-of select="$schools[$i]/SCHOOL_ADDRESS"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
    <!-- STUDENT -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$students[$i]/STUDENT_NAME"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
    <xsl:value-of select="$students[$i]/STUDENT_CLASS"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
    <!-- AWARD -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$awards[$i]/AWARD_NAME"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>  
    <xsl:value-of select="$awards[$i]/AWARD_DATE"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt; count($students) or $i &lt; count($awards)">
        <xsl:call-template name="write-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="schools" select="$schools"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="students" select="$students"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="awards" select="$awards"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```